# How can I calculate an expression by passing it as a string in C#?

Tags: c#, math

In C# I have a string like:

```
string str =  "SUM(1,2,3) + 123 - 45 * 3 "; // Say this is an Expression
```

I van some way so that I have to get the numeric result of the string.

Similar to string I may have AVG, MIN, MAX and other aggregate functions.

Comment: You will need something to parse and evaluate the string. What have you tried?

Comment: You can use regex to extract functions in strings and replace them with calculation results. As to "calculate the string", you can try [Postfix notation(RPN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) via data structure `Stack`.

Comment: You need to tokenize and parse the string. A tokenizer separates the components contained in the string into tokens and the parser generates a parse tree to be able to evaluate the expression. Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@toptensoftware/writing-a-simple-math-expression-engine-in-c-d414de18d4ce). EDIT: if you don't wanna implement it on your own, take a look at [mXparser](http://mathparser.org)

Answer (score 2):

You can work with [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). You can find it on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting/). Version 3.6 needs at least .NETCoreApp 3.1 or .NETStandard 2.0.

```
int result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>("1 + 2");
```

For more examples visit https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform mathematical calculation separately and then parse the result using extension .ToString()